# Jquery form validation style

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I'm using [Jquery's form validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).
I wanna display validation error messages inside the fields that are invalids.

For example, if the email field is invalid, I wanna clear its content and display the message above it. I say above, 'coz there's no need to change the content to the error message.

How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pretty much sums it up:

[jQuery Validation Plugin Example](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example)

I would recommend leaving the bad field values in place when you issue error messages.  It gives the user a chance to see what they've done wrong and correct it.